# Data from PHP not display using autocomplete and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm new with programming, still learning, my language is not good enough, i hope my question is not confused.

```
<input type="hidden" name="code" id="code1">
<input type="text" name="nos" id="nos"/>
```

I'm using jquery ui autocomplete to display data which I input. I send 2 variables to controller using ajax, then success, this is my code.

```
        $("#nos").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            $.ajax({
                dataType:"json",
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>data/header/lookkode",
                data:"source1="+document.getElementById("code1").value+"&source2="+document.getElementById("nos").value,
                success: function(data){
                    // what should i do?
                    console.log(data);
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#nas").val(ui.item.kode)
        },
        change: function(event, ui){
            if(ui.item == null || ui.item == undefined){
                $("#nos").val("");
                $("#nas").val("");
            }
        } 
    });
```

This my controller.

```
   public function lookkode(){;
    $this->code= $_POST['source1'];
    $this->label= $_POST['source2'];
    $this->welcome_m->get_word2(strtolower($this->label),$this->code);
}
```

My problem is, the autocomplete doesn't appear. I don't know why. In console log, the JSON data looks like :

```
[{ "label" : "Item1", "value" : "Item1" }, { "label" : "Item2", "value" : "Item2" }]
```

that's it. I hope some body can help. can give an advice about this. thanks

Comment: What should be your expected output?

Comment: Did you load the jquery, jquery UI and the right CSS?

Comment: When user type, related word will be appear, but the problem is the autocomplete not display it. When i console my browser, i see the JSON data like above. Can u give an advice? is my code wrong?

Comment: Please post your complete code with html. @user2392149

Comment: Did you find any solution? Please go through the link http://www.a100websolutions.in/jqueryui-autocomplete-tutorial/

Comment: thanks all for reply, i was found the solution, just add respond to success function and it's works, thanks a lot..

Comment: You forgot the results.php, like in this solution I whipped up for all those with autocomplete "problems": https://github.com/FREE-FROM-CMS/AutoComplete